# inverting where clause with function, is it possible?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Currently, I'm making a complex query with parameters that will do searches in related tables, this works perfectly, but if I need to say something like "I want to find people who don't have a certain condition", I need to write the same where clause twice: once with IN and once with NOT IN. Is there a way to avoid this scenario? Something like functionX(select id from tablex): boolean

Currently I got something like this:

```sql
   select * from tpatient 
   where 
     (includeparameter1 and TPatient.Id in 
       (select patientid from tdoctorvisit where x ilike parameter1)
     ) 
   or (
        (includeparameter1 = false) and TPatient.Id not in (
       select patientid from tdoctorvisit where x ilike parameter1)
     )
```

Can this somehow be improved to the query below?

```sql
    select * from tpatient where 
  functionX(includeparameter1, TPatient.id, 
    select patientid from tdoctorvisit where x ilike parameter1)
```

This would make my query's a bit smaller as I got a dozen of those where clauses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can write:

```
WHERE includeparameter1 = TPatient.Id in (select patientid from tdoctorvisit where x ilike parameter1)
```

Because:

- `includeparameter1` = a
- `TPatient.Id in (...)` = b

So you have the condition:

```
WHERE (a = true AND b = true) OR (a = false AND b = false)
```

This is the same as `WHERE a = b`

Answer (score 1):

I think a relatively direct method is a lateral join:

```
select p.*
from tpatient p cross join lateral
     (values (p.Id in (select dv.patientid from tdoctorvisit dv where dv.x ilike parameter1) )
     ) v(visitflag)
where (includeparameter1 and v.visitflag) or
      (not includeparameter1 and not v.visitflag);
```